# XAML identify object from resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to identify which shape in a xaml was clicked on.

For this I've added an image to WPF via a static resource:

```xml
<Image Source="{StaticResource di_input}" Name="MyImage" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown">
```

This resource is an exported svg:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <DrawingGroup x:Key="easy_xaml">
        <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0.0,0.0,203.71425,107.84938"/>
        </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
        <DrawingGroup Transform="1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,-5.6774192,-3.2151276">
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#ffff6600" x:Name="Rectangle">
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="5.6774192,5.3225808,106.45161,69.548386"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
.
.
.
    <DrawingImage Drawing="{StaticResource easy_xaml}" x:Key="di_input"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I can get the `GeometryDrawing` that the click fell on, but I have no way to identify which shape in the resource it corresponds to. The `x:Name` property/value I added does not seem to be accessible.

Is there a way to access the `Name` or somehow distinguish the `DrawingGroup`s or `GeometryDrawing`s?

Comment: You can't get the dictionary key of a resource. What you can do is to define an identifier and assign it either to the Name property on the Shape or to the Tag property or to a dedicated attached property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [BionicCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141792/bioniccode)s hint I a was able to come up with a solution: Custom attached properties

The class for the property:

```
public class ShapeId : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Name",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ShapeId),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
            );
    public static void SetName(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(NameProperty, value ?? string.Empty);
    }
    public static string GetName(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(NameProperty);
    }
}
```

Which is added to the resource:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary 
    .
    .
    xmlns:visu="clr-namespace:MyVisu">
.
.
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#ffff6600" visu:ShapeId.Name="Rectangle">
```

and can then be extracted with

```
var name = hitGeometryDrawing.GetValue(ShapeId.NameProperty) as string;
```